# Running QLineEdit::SetText costs much time

Tags: c++, performance, qt

I find that constructing a QLineEdit with a QString costs 0.7s on my low-end PC, while constructing a QTextEdit with a QString costs less than 50ms.

To locate the problem, I try `explicit QLineEdit(const QString &, QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);`
or `void setText(const QString &);` to set text, and the 2 approaches both call `void QWidgetLineControl::updateDisplayText(bool forceUpdate)` in the end, leading to high time cost.

Another phenomenon is that when I set text the second time in the same program, it'll be fast.

But I also find that if I use  `explicit QLineEdit(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);` to construct the widget and use a QPushButton to set text dynamically, there is no delay before the text appears in the widget.

I'd like to know why setting text in a QLineEdit costs so much time and how I can solve it, thanks.

```cpp
QtGuiTest::QtGuiTest(QWidget *parent)
{
/*QLineEdit *edit = NULL;
    QPushButton *button = NULL;*/
    resize(WW, WH);

    edit = new QLineEdit(this);
    button = new QPushButton("button", this);
    edit->setText("hello");//This is slow
    button->move(30, 30);

    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &QtGuiTest::func);
}

void QtGuiTest::func()
{
    edit->setText("hello");//This is fast
}
```

Comment: Since it's QWidget base, the initialization of widgets may give you grief. Is there any reason why you're not using QObject at QtQuick2 controls instead of QWidgets?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you arrive at these timings (timing such things reliably is notoriously difficult).  Initialization of the `QLineEdit` may have several steps.  If you set the text in the constructor all init steps may be forced immediately.  When initializing with a null pointer and setting the text later via a `QPushButton` it's possible that a lot of the init steps are integrated within the event loop and do not, therefore, show up in your timings.

Comment: I tested the time again and find that you are right, and I wrote an answer here.Thank for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the second comment, I now realize where the problem is.

Not using the debugger, I measure the time cost again.
I find that if I don't set text before the window shows up, there will be nothing in the window and a 0.7s initialization will happen that shows the widgets.
While setting text before the window shows up will make the new window filled with widgets, not needing to load again.

According to the research result, the 0.7s process I mentioned in the qusetion is caused by Qt's general initialization.